# PhoneGap interop

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, windows-phone-8

**SmartPhone app should run on**

- iOS
- Android
- WindowsPhone

**Use-case**

1. Capture video
2. Go through some rich UI
3. Video processing

**Implementation**

1. Use PhoneGap for 'Video Capture' & 'UI'
2. Use OS specific implementation for the 'Video processing' part ( 'Objective-C' for iPhone, C++ for Android & C++/COM for WindowsPhone )

**Before putting more stakes into PhoneGap, I would like to know IF**

- PhoneGap support the above use-case, does it support OS Specific interop ( for video processing ) on a per OS basis?
- PhoneGap supports a single solution/project including a per OS native implementation for the 'video processing' part ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your Use-case

1. Confirm. Take a look on [captureVideo](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureVideo) api
2. Confirm. Phonegap supports jquerymobile and other mobile web frameworks.
3. Conform. This could be implemented as an additional PhoneGap plugin (s). Ideally you will have the same js file across all platforms with api definition and different platform specific implementation for each platform.